# Fastest way of storing non-adjacent d registers with NEON intrinsics

Tags: ios, neon

I am porting 32bit NEON asm code to NEON intrinsics, and I am wondering if this code can be written in a concise way using intrinsics:

```
vst4.32 {d0[0], d2[0], d4[0], d6[0]}, [%[v1]]!
```

1) The previous code operates on `q` registers, but when it comes to storage, instead of using `q0`, `q1`, `q2` and `q3`, it has to recreate vectors which have each part in one of the `d` registers, e.g. `v1[0] = d0[0], v1[1] = d2[0] ... v2[0] = d0[1], v2[1] = d2[1] ... v3[0] = d1[0], v3[1] = d3[0] ...` etc.

This operation is a one-liner in asm, but with intrinsics I don't know if I can do that without first splitting high and low bits and building a new `float32x4x4_t` variable to feed to `vst4_f32`.

Is that possible?

2) I'm not entirely sure of what `[%[v1]]!` does (yes, I googled quite a bit): it should be a reference to a variable named `v1` and the exclamation mark will do *writeback*, which should mean the pointer is increased by the same amount that was written by the instruction on the same line.

Correct? Any way of replicating that with intrinsics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more investigation I found this specific instruction to [store a specific lane of an array of 4 vectors](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491h/BABDDHDG.html), so no need to split into high and low bits variables:

```
float32x4x4_t u = { q0, q1, q2, q3 };
vst4q_lane_f32(v1, u, 0);
v1 += 4;
```

Writeback is just an increased pointer, as @charlesbaylis wrote.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, a sufficiently smart compiler could use the instruction you want for the vst4_f32 intrinsic, but in practice, no compiler is that good.

To get the post-index writeback, you can write

```
vst4_f32(ptr, v);
ptr += 4;
```

Some compilers will recognise this. GCC 5.1 (when released) will do this in at least some cases.

[Edit: misread the question, vst4q_lane_f32 does map to the required instruction perfectly]

Comment: Thanks I did something similar to this, see my answer.

Comment: PS: as the question is tagged iOS the compiler is Clang only

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be inline assembly.
Anyway, the answers are:

1) No

2) Yes